# Mounting my two external drives, I find the media folder is full and I have to move it to a seperate partition to avoid the main drive filling up

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, fstab, external-hdd

When I add my two external hard drives, I mount them to folders in /media. They currently show 447.8 GiB of 915.8 GiB free (51% used) and 344.2 GiB of 915.8 GiB free (62% used).
However, /media shows: 0 bytes of 264.2 GiB free (100% used).

I've had to move /media to a separate partition to avoid the main drive filling up and having no free space.

How can I mount the external drives so their usage is not counted in media?

```
System Info:
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-57-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-1603 v3 @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 31.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Quadro K4200/PCIe/SSE2

fstab:
UUID=eb06fd29-0646-4a01-8366-2fd93804fbb3                  /                    ext4   errors=remount-ro                                           0 1
UUID=89C6-AAB6                                             /boot/efi            vfat   umask=0077                                                  0 1
/swapfile                                                  none                 swap   sw                                                          0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/b9242157-b6d5-402c-8efb-d0bf39f05530 /media auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=media 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/9de24f5a-7d64-49e3-98d4-435798b5ebeb  /media/ExternalHDD   auto   nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=ExternalHDD     0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ea38682e-28a3-4b36-9461-f2a1b66332c3  /media/Backup        auto   nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Backup           0 0
/dev/sdb2                                                  /home                ext4   


df -h output:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3.2G  2.5M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda3       219G   21G  188G  10% /
tmpfs            16G  382M   16G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda2       512M  6.2M  506M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb2       458G  205G  230G  48% /home
/dev/sdc3       265G  265G     0 100% /media
/dev/sde1       916G  541G  329G  63% /media/ExternalHDD
tmpfs           3.2G  112K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdd1       916G  425G  448G  49% /media/Backup
```

Comment: Please update your question with the output of ˝df -h˝

Comment: The external mounts don't count against the space in /media other than a few bytes for the mount point. /media is typically a dir in / that just contains some username dirs, which contain the mount points for external media, so little space is used.  Looks like you filled it up directly instead of filling up disks mounted there.

Comment: I agree that is what should happen. I have not saved any files into /media. campbell@desktop3:/media$ ls -l
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   9 campbell campbell  4096 Sep  1 13:31 Backup
drwxr-x---+  2 campbell campbell  4096 Dec  8 14:19 campbell
drwxr-xr-x  12 campbell campbell  4096 Sep  1 12:49 ExternalHDD
drwx------   2 campbell campbell 16384 Aug 31 16:13 lost+found